# Pandas series extract with regular experession

Tags: pandas

Need to extract the following from Pandas column which has the following values

```
8-9 yrs
7-12 yrs
4-6 yrs
```

Would need 9,12,6 updated in the column .

Comment: Sorry, so my answer not working? Why accepting wrong answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DataFrame with `df` with a column `a`

[image]

using `re` library with `findall` function with regex

```
import re
df.a.apply(lambda x : re.findall(r'-(\d+)', x))
```

[image]

Comment: I needed the extract function , with your regex and it works as expected

Comment: Hi Pushparaj, This will work `df.a.apply(lambda x : x.str.extract('-(\d+)')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex for get numbers after `-` or `split` with indexing, last if necessary cast to integer:

```
df['B1'] = df.A.str.extract('-(\d+)', expand=True)
df['B2'] = df.A.str.split(n=1).str[0].str.split('-').str[1].astype(int)
df['B3'] = df.A.str.split('-|\s+').str[1].astype(int)
print (df)
          A  B1  B2  B3
0   8-9 yrs   9   9   9
1  7-12 yrs  12  12  12
2   4-6 yrs   6   6   6
```